# Java 7 - JLayer, no LockableUI

Tags: java, swing, java-7, jlayer

Having never before used `J(X)Layer`, I can see references to `LockableUI` over the internet. But it looks , in Java 7, like all we have of seemingly big 'parent' API (JX...) is two classes `JLayer` and `LayerUI`.

Is there some 'hidden' way of blocking `JLayer`'s contents I haven't found yet, or do we handcraft this?

One way I can see is registering `JLayer` via `setLayerEventMask` and then meticulously eating the input events with `InputEvent.consume()`.

Not a big deal, but as `JLayer` seems a natural way to disable it's contents, so maybe it's already there somewhere?

Comment: Did you check this? https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2266000

Comment: @lbalazscs: No, I doidn't check this thread, thanks for input. The solution there is precisely to `consume` `InputEvents`. So I guess that's the way to go.